# $scope.$watch not firing (controller as vm)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

No matter what I tried from answers to the same question, I can't get this to work.
notice I'm also using a [tr-state checkbox directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347384/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-a-single-tri-state-checkbox-within-angularjs).

https://plnkr.co/edit/mBy0mm0XZNzo9EnsmL9Q?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  
   vm.flags = [
        { field: "PaymentMade", title: "Payment Made", isSeaAir: false, filter: null },
        { field: "isInTransit", title: "In Transit", isSeaAir: false, filter: null },
        { field: "Docked", title: "Docked", isSeaAir: false, filter: null },
        { field: "isDockedPartial", title: "Docked Partial", isSeaAir: true, filter: null },

    ];
  $scope.$watch('vm.flags' , function handleFlagssChange(newVla, oldVal) {
        console.log("flags changed");
    });
});

app.directive('indeterminate', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            var truthy = true;
            var falsy = false;
            var nully = null;
            ctrl.$formatters = [];
            ctrl.$parsers = [];
            ctrl.$render = function () {
                var d = ctrl.$viewValue;
                el.data('checked', d);
                switch (d) {
                    case truthy:
                        el.prop('indeterminate', false);
                        el.prop('checked', true);
                        break;
                    case falsy:
                        el.prop('indeterminate', false);
                        el.prop('checked', false);
                        break;
                    default:
                        el.prop('indeterminate', true);
                }
            };
            el.bind('click', function () {
                var d;
                switch (el.data('checked')) {
                    case falsy:
                        d = truthy;
                        break;
                    case truthy:
                        d = nully;
                        break;
                    default:
                        d = falsy;
                }
                ctrl.$setViewValue(d);
                scope.$apply(ctrl.$render);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <label>Flags: </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info" ng-repeat="f in vm.flags" style="margin-right:5px;">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="f.filter" indeterminate />
            {{f.title}} | {{f.filter}}
        </label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add third parameter `true`, to check correct for object equality.

```
$scope.$watch('vm.flags' , function handleFlagssChange(newVla, oldVal) {
    console.log("flags changed");
}, true);
```

[Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

> When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is
>   determined according to the angular.equals function. To save the value
>   of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used.
>   This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse
>   memory and performance implications.